Go with Postgres and Docker - 127.0.0.11:53: no such host
I use docker compose to run my application on a VPS server. It consists of a golang backend and PostgreSQL DB. While the backend connected to the DB completely fine on my PC, it fails to do so on the VPS. I've listed host.docker.internal in the .env file, I guess the problem be somewhere there.
Error:
2024/10/15 21:18:16 /app/config/database.go:39

[error] failed to initialize database, got error failed to connect to `user=_ database=_`: hostname resolving error: lookup host.docker.internal on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host

panic: failed to connect to `user=_ database=_`: hostname resolving error: lookup host.docker.internal on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host

goroutine 1 [running]:

politex/backend/config.Connect()

    /app/config/database.go:42 +0x378

main.main()

    /app/main.go:12 +0x25

docker-compose.yml:
services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    restart: always
    image: postgres:16.4
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: _
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: _
      POSTGRES_DB: _
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  pgdata:

.env:
DB_HOST=host.docker.internal
DB_PASS=_
DB_PORT=5432
DB_USER=_
DB_NAME=_

database.go:
package config

import (
    ...
)

var Database *gorm.DB

func Connect() error {
    envErr := godotenv.Load()
    if envErr != nil {
        panic(envErr)
    }

    user := os.Getenv("DB_USER")
    host := os.Getenv("DB_HOST")
    pass := os.Getenv("DB_PASS")
    name := os.Getenv("DB_NAME")
    port := os.Getenv("DB_PORT")

    dsn := fmt.Sprintf("host=%v user=%v password=%v dbname=%v port=%v sslmode=disable TimeZone=Europe/Moscow", host, user, pass, name, port)

    var err error
    Database, err = gorm.Open(postgres.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{})

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    Database.AutoMigrate(&entities.Note{})

    return nil
}


Is the title IP address and port correct? Port 53 is the default port for DNS and 127.0.0.11 looks like it should have been 127.0.0.1.

@HansKilian yeah, it is. That's why I'm pretty confused

So what is host.docker.internal? Who defines host.docker.internal on the server?  The database service name you specified is db, so you should use db.

@HansKilian why would it be not correct? All addresses in 127.0.0.0/8 resolve to a loopback (generally) and a lot of software binds to various addresses there. Eg systemd's dns is 127.0.0.53. And docker-compose uses 127.0.0.11

Solved:
I did assign the static IP to the db container and added it to .env file (and yeah, setting host to "db" didn't work for some reason)
docker-compose.yml:
services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      - static
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    restart: always
    image: postgres:16.4
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: _
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: _
      POSTGRES_DB: _
    networks:
        static:
          ipv4_address:
            172.20.128.2
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  pgdata:
networks:
  static:
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: "172.20.0.0/16"

.env:
DB_HOST=172.20.128.2
DB_PASS=_
DB_PORT=5432
DB_USER=_
DB_NAME=_


Did you tried setting DB_HOST=db?
As 'db' is the service name for the database then the host name. Or do you have a reason not to use db?
It's also recommended to define a network in your docker compose and tie your containers to this network.

By default, compose creates a docker bridge network and attaches the containers to it, so there's no need to do it manually.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
